# Git Shell - go command not found

Tags: git, bash, shell, command

I found this course on a website called Lynda.com (some of you probably know about this website).

The course was called: `Code Clinic: Go`. So, I'm using something called `Go` or `Golang` and I downloaded this command program called `Git Shell`, and whenever I execute a Go Command, I get this message:

```
bash: go : command not found
```

Does anybody know what's going on?

Comment: Can you be more specific? You should describe more precisely where is the problem. What command are you trying to run?

Comment: How did you (attempt to) install Go?

Answer (score 11):

You have to put the Go executable in your PATH:

1) `cd ~`

2) `vi .bashrc`

3) Inside .bashrc, enter the following: `PATH=$PATH:/c/Go/bin`

Restart git bash and you should now have the `go` command

Comment: I had to add it this way `export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/go/bin`

Answer (score 5):

You need to set GOPATH environment variable with the path of your GO installation directory.

For example if your Go installation directory is C:\Go

Open a bash terminal and run the following:

```
GOPATH=/c/Go/bin
```

Then type `go version` to check if it works

you should see the go version you installed

Comment: Can you explain me why it says to set it to the workspace rather that GO installation directory here : https://golang.org/doc/code.html#GOPATH

Comment: in gitbash for Windows, the /c/Users/<username>/.bashrc file can point to program files with `GOPATH='/c/Program Files/Go/bin'`

Answer (score 2):

The Go compiler is not part of Git Bash; you need to install it separately.

See [the download page on http://golang.org/](https://golang.org/dl/); for Windows, one of the MSI installers is most likely to be appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the issue is with environment variables. You can get a quick and easy fix by running Go installer then choose 'repair' from the installation options.